# On iOS and Cocoa Touch, can there be race condition for touchesBegan and timerFired?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Say, if `timerFired` (timer handler) is called by earlier set up using `NSTimer` or `CADisplayLink`, and `touchesBegan` is also called when a user touches the screen, can there be any race condition happening in the code inside the two handlers (timer handler and touch event handler)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a timer handler and `touchesBegan` both run on the main thread, then there the code in them cannot intermix (they're on the same thread). This is the normal situation.

There can be race conditions in that the timer may run before or after the `touchesBegan`, but they can't run at the same time if they're on the same thread. They would only be on different threads if you attached the timer to another thread's runloop (which is a very unusual thing to do).